# What's the difference between the Three Families of Fortinet SPUs?

Tags: fortinet, cpu

Why Fortinet name their CPU's like: NETWORK PROCESSOR 7 (NP7), CONTENT PROCESSOR 9 (CP9) and SECURITY PROCESSING UNIT (SP5).

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the relevant information on this page from Fortinet:
https://www.fortinet.com/products/fortigate/fortiasic

Each kind of processor optimizes different features, by handling them directly in specialized hardware (ASIC) rather than in software (where it would be handled by a generic purpose processor)

- The network (and main) processor, NP7, speeds up layer 2 and layer 3 functions, like IP routing, IPSEC encryption and NAT. It is more adapted for a layer 3 switch
- the content processor, CP9, is a co-processor that analyses the traffic and perform IPS functions, and even anti-virus, adapted to firewalls
- the Security Processing Unit, SP5:

> consolidates both network and content processing functions on a
> single chip,